# Can I use regex to specify a pattern that matches the correct number of opening and closing brackets?

Tags: regex

Suppose I have the following string:

```
Prop1=a,Prop2=[Prop2_1=b,Prop2_2=c],Prop3=[Prop3_1=[Prop3_2_1=e,Prop3_2_2=f,Prop3_2_3=g],Prop3_2=d],...
```

I can extract the value of `Prop1` very easily, with the pattern `(?<=Prop1=).*?(?=,)`.

For `Prop2` I want to extract `[Prop2_1=b,Prop2_2=c]`, and for Prop3, I want to extract `[Prop3_1=[Prop3_2_1=e,Prop3_2_2=f,Prop3_2_3=g],Prop3_2=d]`.

But here's the thing: I don't know in advance if what I'm looking for is nested, or how many degrees of nesting there are.

Is there a single regex expression that can handle the general case?

**Edit**
I have been reminded that I need to specify which flavour of regex. I'm using python (`import re`).

Comment: You can use `(?<=Prop3=)(?:(\[(?:[^][]++|(?1))*])|[^,]*)` if you use PCRE. See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/Gz4fIl/1). Or, `Prop3=\K(?:(\[(?:[^][]++|(?1))*])|[^,]*)` (see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/Gz4fIl/2)). The only question, what is the programming language/regex flavor that you are using?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thank you for the reminder. I'm using python, but I'll try to decompose your patterns to see if I can modify them. Much appreciated.

Comment: You cannot use `re` because it does not support recursion and regex subroutines. You need to install the PyPi `regex` module using kind of `pip install regex` and use `import regex as re` before trying my suggestion.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Nice, thanks. If you make your responses an answer I'll be happy to upvote and accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `re` because it does not support recursion and regex subroutines. You need to install the PyPi `regex` module using `pip install regex` and then use `import regex as re` (or `import regex` and then use `regex` instead of `re`).

The pattern you can use is

```py
Prop3=\K(?:(\[(?:[^][]++|(?1))*])|[^,]*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Gz4fIl/2). *Details*:

- `Prop3=` - `Prop3=` text
- `\K` - match reset operator that discards the text matched so far
- `(?:(\[(?:[^][]++|(?1))*])|[^,]*)` - a non-capturing group that matches

  - `(\[(?:[^][]++|(?1))*])` - Group 1: `[`, then zero or more repetitions of one or more chars other than `[` and `]` or the whole Group 1 pattern recursed, and then a `]` char
  - `|` - or
  - `[^,]*` - zero or more chars other than `,`

```py
import regex
text = "Prop1=a,Prop2=[Prop2_1=b,Prop2_2=c],Prop3=[Prop3_1=[Prop3_2_1=e,Prop3_2_2=f,Prop3_2_3=g],Prop3_2=d],..."

print( regex.search(r'Prop1=\K(?:(\[(?:[^][]++|(?1))*])|[^,]*)', text).group() )
# => a
print( regex.search(r'Prop2=\K(?:(\[(?:[^][]++|(?1))*])|[^,]*)', text).group() )
# => [Prop2_1=b,Prop2_2=c]
print( regex.search(r'Prop3=\K(?:(\[(?:[^][]++|(?1))*])|[^,]*)', text).group() )
# => [Prop3_1=[Prop3_2_1=e,Prop3_2_2=f,Prop3_2_3=g],Prop3_2=d]
```

See the [Python demo online](https://tio.run/##pVDLDoIwELzzFY0eaKFpAr2ZrHyAF@@lEMQKHISm1gQT/h15iCfDQS47szubmc3qly2bmvd9ddeNscioQrWOVa1FgHZn0@gAMjpiCGKCNIDLPEhDyOVE@azxQfuQcU3RhYdw@3IOhVwauErKGNs5jjZVbfEczx4qM3mJjTvnxyccHXAshioSKaTvdzgKCPEk6URCpUdcisaTCStM89SYIIL2CI4oW/ENN/j@/MRKFt@a9c9n@/4N).